# Как сохранить ссылку на картинку в String, а потом ее открыть?

Tags: android, файлы, bitmap

Нужно взять урл картинки из галереи и сохранить в базу ссылку, чтобы потом можно было открыть. Сcылку сохранил, но файл не открыватся.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        Uri uri = data.getData();


        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
            imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            uriImg = uri.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

пытаюсь открыть, но ничего не происходит.

```
 File imgFile = new  File(uriImg);
                if (imgFile.getAbsoluteFile().exists()){
                    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

Comment: Сыылка выглядит так `content://media/external/images/media/64`

Comment: А разрешения за запись/чтение файлов с девайса есть в манифесте?..

Comment: Странно, что картинка не имеет расширения

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission> вот это в манифесте

Comment: да сохраняет ссылку без разширения, но я пробовал в ручнуб добавить .jpg. Без результата

Comment: А под таким адресом точно есть картинка? Руками проверяли?

Comment: content://media/external/images/media/64 +".jpg" пробовал

Comment: content://media/external/images/media/64 Судя по всему эот вообще не название файла. А что тогда? Как по урл получить адрес файла?

Answer (score 1):

Дайте доступ для записи и чтения в AndroidManifest.xml и попробуйте так:

```
if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

    Uri uri = data.getData();
    imageView.setImageURI(uri);
}
```

Comment: Проблема не в том что картинка  вообще не открывается. А в том что ссылка котора сохраняется на файл выглядит ка какаята чепуха. `content://media/external/images/media/64`

Answer (score 1):

Данная кострукция возвращает вменяевый строковый url картинки:
Все спасибо за отзывы.

```
    String uriImg;
    Uri uri = data.getData();
    Cursor cursor = null;
                    try {
                        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                        cursor = getApplication().getContentResolver().query(uri, proj, null, null, null);
                        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                        cursor.moveToFirst();
                        uriImg = cursor.getString(column_index);

                    } finally {
                        if (cursor != null) {
                            cursor.close();
                        }
                    }
```